# jsonbin API problems with Swift

Tags: python, json, swift, alamofire, alamofire5

I'm building a little app that talks to the [jsonbin](https://jsonbin.io) API with Alamofire. Their API docs cover using Python to "put" or "update" the JSON file data  extensively in Python. I'm working on doing that in Swift 5.

My problem is when I attempt to use a put command to send data to a specific file. See code:

```
import AlamoFire

func sendData()
    {
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-Master-Key": "x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x",
            "X-Bin-Meta": "false"
        ]
        
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.app.name", qos: .background, attributes: .concurrent)
        
        do{
            
            var testData = [
            
                "title": "My Test Task",
                "date": "My Date",
                "complete": "Completion Status",
                "assignee": "Bob Jones"
            
            ]
            
            AF.request("https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/x-x-x-x-x-x-x", method: .put, parameters: testData, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON(queue: queue) { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(_):
                    print("Success!")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            print("Error occured.")
        }

        
    }
```

I'm trying to send a simple JSON structure over. The error I receive is this:

```
esponseValidationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(code: 400))
```

Their API docs say that an error 400 typically means:

- You need to pass Content-Type set to application/json
- Invalid Bin Id provided
- Bin (JSON Data) cannot be blank

I have verified all of these requirements are correct.

Here is functioning Python code as per their docs:

```
import requests
url = 'https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/x-x-x-x-x-x'
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'X-Master-Key': 'x-x-x-x-x-x-x'
}
data = {"sample": "Hello World"}

req = requests.put(url, json=data, headers=headers)
print(req.text)
```

Is there something I'm missing? Are the data types different? Is the `testData` Swift variable different than the `data` Python variable? How might I go about "putting" data to the RESTful API with Swift and Alamofire 5?

Thanks!

Comment: (1) Have you looked at the text of the response? I'm not familiar with AlamoFire, but often APIs will include useful information in the error response that will help you identify the problem. (2) What if you target something like [postbin](https://www.toptal.com/developers/postbin/) (or just `nc`) instead of the actual API and compare the working request with the non-working request?

Comment: @larsks The response text is the same as the error.

Comment: Well, that leaves (2), I guess.

Comment: Add `encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default,` between `parameters: testData,` & `headers: headers`. Currently, it's not sent as JSON, it's sent as URL encoded. You can add `.cURLDescription { print("JSONBIN curl: \($0)") }` between `request()` and `validate()`: `request(...).cURLDescription { print("JSONBIN curl: \($0)") }.validate()` and see the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current parameters are not sent as JSON, but url encoded.

You can use the cURL description tool method of Alamofire to see how it's sent:

```
AF.request("https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/x-x-x-x-x-x-x",
           method: .put,
           parameters: testData,
           headers: headers)
.cURLDescription { print("JSONBIN curl: \($0)") }
.validate()
.responseJSON(queue: queue) { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(_):
        print("Success!")
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

And you'd get:

```
JSONBIN curl: $ curl -v \
    -X PUT \
    -H "Accept-Language: fr-US;q=1.0" \
    -H "User-Agent: Alamofired/1.0 (ZzZ; build:1; iOS 16.4.0) Alamofire/5.4.0" \
    -H "Accept-Encoding: br;q=1.0, gzip;q=0.9, deflate;q=0.8" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "X-Bin-Meta: false" \
    -H "X-Master-Key: x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x" \
    -d "assignee=Bob%20Jones&complete=Completion%20Status&date=My%20Date&title=My%20Test%20Task" \
    "https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/x-x-x-x-x-x-x"
```

The important part being

```
-d "assignee=Bob%20Jones&complete=Completion%20Status&date=My%20Date&title=My%20Test%20Task"
```

So you need to tell to send the parameters as JSON:

```
AF.request("https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/x-x-x-x-x-x-x",
           method: .put,
           parameters: testData,
           encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default,
           headers: headers)
.cURLDescription { print("JSONBIN curl: \($0)") }
.validate()
.responseJSON(queue: queue) { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(_):
        print("Success!")
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

And then, the cURL output parameter line is:

```
-d "{\"date\":\"My Date\",\"title\":\"My Test Task\",\"complete\":\"Completion Status\",\"assignee\":\"Bob Jones\"}" \
```

Unrelated to your code, but:
There is no need for a `do`/`catch`, there is no `try`, and it would be recommended to print the `error` if there is really an `try`, not just `print("Error occured.")`. but `print("Error occurred: \(error)")`.

Also, `responseJSON()` is deprecated, in favor of `Codable` and `responseDecodable(of:)`. If you still want to use `JSONSerialization` (which is innerly called in `responseJSON()`), use `responseData()` and call it yourself.

Comment: Thank you much my friend! That success message has never been so sweet to see.